# Writing a callback function in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, coffeescript

I'm having a little trouble understanding how to write call back functions in coffeescript functions. I have created this script and a couple functions...

```
$('form').submit (e) ->
    console.log $(this)
    e.preventDefault()
    if $(this).hasClass 'volunteer-check-out-find-me-form'
        showFormLoader $(this), $(this).parent('aside.form').sibling('.form-loader'), ->
            console.log 'finished'

showFormLoader = (form, formLoader, callback) ->
    'showing loader and hiding form'
    form.fadeOut ->
        formLoader.addClass('show').one 'webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', ->
            console.log 'calling back'
            callback()
```

But I'm getting this error in the console when I submit the form

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

On the line the function call is on, am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: On what line do you get the error? The code looks fine.

Comment: It's on the line that the function call is on, where I pass the parameters and the anonymous function

Comment: So it is saying that `showFormLoader` is not a function?

Comment: But *which function call*? I count 18 invocations in your snippet!

Comment: The call to showFormLoader line 5 of the snippet

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `sibling` function, it does have `siblings` though. The full error message or a quick demo would have gotten this solved about three hours ago.

Comment: mu that was the only error I was getting

Comment: when that event function gets called, i'm pretty sure `this` will refer to the event, not the form. I would expect you'd want to reference `e.currentTarget` instead. That may be the issue inside the function where you reference `form.fadeOut`.

Answer (score 0):

Coffee script doesn't allow forward reference for functions the way Javascript does, so you need to move `showFormLoader` above your `submit` handler. That way, the declaration precedes the reference. As an aside, this is, IMO a pain point for Coffeescript.

So this fails:

```
baz(3)

baz = (n) ->
  console.log n
```

with the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at Object.<anonymous> (untitled:51:3)
  at Object.<anonymous> (untitled:57:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

But of course this succeeds:

```
baz = (n) ->
  console.log n

baz(3)
```

I hope I understood your question properly.